# Postgis - ST_ShortestLine not correct with lat lon

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm calculating the shortest line between a Line and a Point for very short distances (some meters), using Postgis ST_ShortestLine:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_ShortestLine(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2.33123610021 48.87902639841)', 4326),
                ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 2.33122725689 48.87902421718, 2.33123229444 48.87901190847)', 4326))
        ) As sline;
```

I get a result which does not seem coherent, the given line not being the shortest one:

```
LINESTRING(2.33123610021 48.87902639841,2.331227760998549 48.87902298544515)
```

Here is a drawing of the result, using the Mercator projection (JOSM).

[image: Drawing of the points]

What could explain this?

Comment: Are you sure that the solution s not correct? Which projection does your image use? One that preserves angles?

Comment: My projection uses Mercator (JOSM).

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on your eyes to determine if the drawn line is the shortest one you might have been mislead to this conclusion. `ST_ShortestLine` will return a line with exact same length of `ST_Distance`, which is the minimum 2D cartesian distance of two geometries. And it is exactly what is happening:

```
WITH j (line,point) AS (
  VALUES ('SRID=4326;POINT(2.33123610021 48.87902639841)',
          'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.33122725689 48.87902421718, 2.33123229444 48.87901190847)')
)
SELECT   
  ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(point,line)), -- length of the shortest line
  ST_Distance(line,point),                -- distance between 'point' and 'line'
  ST_AsEWKT(ST_ShortestLine(point,line))  -- the shortest line as EWKT 
FROM j;

       st_length       |      st_distance      |                                       st_asewkt                                        
-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9.010592472335791e-06 | 9.010592472335791e-06 | SRID=4326;LINESTRING(2.331227760998549 48.87902298544515,2.33123610021 48.87902639841)
(1 row)
```

Perhaps you share the result you're expecting and we can go from there.

Comment: Maybe the drawing is misleading me (JOSM using Mercator). For me the shortest line should be the one between the point and the edge of the line (as the distances are really short)

Comment: And if I calculate a Haversine distance between the point and the edge, I get : 

>>> haversine((48.87902639841, 2.33123610021), (48.87902421718, 2.33122725689))
0.6906773249543592m
And a haversine distance of the shortest line : 

>>> haversine((48.87902639841, 2.33123610021),(48.87902298544515,2.331227760998549))
0.7182701331787816m

Comment: Or the same with geography:
select ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.33123610021 48.87902639841)'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.33122725689 48.87902421718)'))
----> 0.69251929

select ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.33123610021 48.87902639841)'), ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.331227760998549 48.87902298544515)'))
-----> 0.71985964

Comment: @JeanCarriere fair point, but I believe that the 2nd point of the shortest line isn't a "real point" in the linestring at all. But yes, its much closer to the edge. take a look: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=95a76bd7018bd5c56f46782c50bd82ad (it does not run at db<>fiddle because it lacks postgis)

Comment: Runs on pg13: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=95a76bd7018bd5c56f46782c50bd82ad